# Problem with Child-Theme using of foundation-framework

Tags: functions, child-theme, parent-theme, framework

I have created a child theme. The parent theme uses Foundation-Framework. I also  have included foundation framework to my child theme and trying to add a simple navbar with dropdown but the dropdown is not seems to be a dropdown. Here is my functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_my_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX );
/**
 * Enqueue parent theme styles considering styles dependencies.
 */
function _my_child_theme_styles() {
    // Parent styles that need to be loaded before the child theme styles.
    $parent_styles = array(  'parent_style_1' => 'style.css', 'parent_style_2' => 'styles/modern.css' );
    // Enqueue parent styles using the custom handles and considering styles dependencies.
    foreach( $parent_styles as $handle => $style ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( $handle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $style, array( 'hrb-normalize', 'hrb-foundation' ) );
    }

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array_keys( $parent_styles )
    );


}

//=========================
//      OTHER STYLES
//=========================
function getthejobdone_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'OpenSans', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700' ); //font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_theme_file_uri('/css/vendor/font-awesome.min.css') );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'foundationCss', get_theme_file_uri('/css/vendor/foundation.css') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getthejobdone_styles' );


//=============================
//      OTHER JAVASCRIPTS wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer )
//=============================
function getthejobdone_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints', get_theme_file_uri('/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'what-input-JS', get_theme_file_uri('/js/vendor/what-input.js'), NULL, NULL, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundationJS', get_theme_file_uri('/js/vendor/foundation.js'), array('jquery'), '6.4.2', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'AppJS', get_theme_file_uri('/js/app.js'), array('jquery'), NULL, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getthejobdone_js' );

//=====================
//      FEATURES
//=====================
function getthejobdone_features() {
    add_theme_support('title-tag'); // dynamic title for every pages
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'getthejobdone_features' );
```

If I cut `foundation.js` and paste it just before the `$parent_styles` then the dropdown works but there shows a lot of errors in the `console`. So where I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: If your parent theme already has foundation then why are you adding it again? Any scripts and styles your parent theme loads will be on the child theme as well.

Comment: Thank you for figuring it out but without adding foundation to my child theme it's not working anymore, probably I m missing something in child theme.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What sort of errors are you getting? Does foundation require a special class name or html structure to work correctly?

Comment: Yes, foundation is very similar to bootstrap and I used it's classes properly from their docs but it's just not working, obviously I m doing something wrong which still I can't figure it out. Bellow is the demo navbar taken from their docs

Comment: `<ul class="menu dropdown" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Two</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">dd-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dd-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dd-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>`

Comment: For this time being, I removed foundation from child-theme which I should and now I m getting the navbar without any style and dis-organized but there is no error in the console now.

Comment: Can you show your console errors?

Comment: Your question should be specific to WordPress. Generic PHP/JS/SQL/HTML/CSS questions might be better asked at Stack Overflow or another appropriate Stack Exchange network site. Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes.

Comment: Hi Mat, Sorry about that. Since the problem only with the child theme so it seems to me that this is the right place to ask.

Comment: Is the child theme your own creation or is it provided by the theme developers?

Comment: Hi Nath, you can see errors here: https://goo.gl/jtzsWa

Comment: @Mat, this is not provided by the theme developers

Comment: Have you tried just using the basic child theme implementation as detailed in the WordPress Codex - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes rather than using your own function `_my_child_theme_styles()`? I'd also try commenting out your function that is re-adding the JS - `getthejobdone_js()`

Comment: Yes, first time I tried that but the parent theme doesn't uses its style.css for any styles and that is why I implemented it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76035/discussion-between-mat-and-shihab-ul-h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a chat discussion with the OP, I found out that the theme being used was HireBee. After some investigation it appears that HireBee only uses a very minimal version of the Foundation framework, which didn't include the Menu and Dropdown Menu components.

The answer in this case would be to dequeue the parent themes version of the Foundation framework CSS:

```
// Disable the HireBee Foundation framework.
wp_dequeue_style( 'hrb-foundation-css' );
```

and then download a custom version of the Foundation framework from https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/ including the required components - in this case the Navigation components 'Menu' and 'Dropdown Menu'

The customised version of the Foundation framework will then need to be enqueued from the Child themes `functions.php` file.